# Non-isomorphic unit groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Show that the group $U_8$ of units modulo $8$ is not isomorphic to $U_{10}$?

This is my answer. Check it for me please.

Suppose $U_8$ is isomorphic to $U_{10}$, $3 ∈ U_{10}$ and order of $3$ in $U_{10}$ is $4$.
But there is no element of order $4$ in  $U_8$, which is contradiction. $U_8$ is not  isomorphic to $U_{10}$.

Comment: seems fine to me

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed correct.  Note that isomorphisms will preserve the orders of elements.

**Proof**: Consider any $a \in G$ of order $n$, and suppose we have an isomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$.  First, recall that, for any group homomorphism, the identity in the first group will always map to the identity in the second group.  Thus:

$$\phi(e) = \phi(a^n)  = \phi(a)^n = e$$

Since $3 \in U_{10}$ has order $4$ and there is no element of order $4$ in $U_8$, then we conclude $U_{10} \ncong U_8$.